# Ansible: clear host errors after handler call

Tags: ansible

**What I Do**

For Bare Metal deployment, I configure interfaces on **CentOS 7** servers via `ansible 2.7.9`.

Sometimes, the interface definitions change

```
- name: Copy sysctl and ifcfg- files from templates.
  template: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }}
  with_items:
    [...]
    - { src: 'network.j2', dest: '/etc/sysconfig/network' }
  notify:
    - Restart network service
    - Wait for reconnect
    - Reset host errors
```

which is why I call a handler to **restart** the `network.service` when a change happens:

```
- name: Restart network service
  service:
    name: network
    state: restarted

- name: Reset host errors
  meta: clear_host_errors

- name: Wait for reconnect
  wait_for_connection:
    connect_timeout: 20
    sleep: 5
    delay: 5
    timeout: 600
```

**What I want**

I can't get `ansible` to **not** quit the run when the *Restart network service* handler fails. Since the service restart is working fine on the host itself, I either want the restart to always exit with `RC=0` or clear the host error after the failing handler call. In the following list, is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

**What I tried**

- `ignore errors: true`, `failed_when: false`, `changed_when: false` directives. Either with `shell/command` module or `service` module in the restart network handler block.
- `meta: clear_host_errors` directly below the `- name: Copy sysctl and ifcfg- files from templates.` block
- calling `meta: clear_host_errors` as a handler
- Having the handler *Restart network service* exit with `|| true`
- `async/poll` variants for *Restart network service*
- setting `Pipelining` to **false**

I always end up with:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [os : Restart network service] *******************************************************************
fatal: [host-redacted]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to aa.bb.cc.dd closed.", "unreachable": true}

RUNNING HANDLER [os : Reset host errors] *************************************************************************
fatal: [host-redacted]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to aa.bb.cc.dd closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 0}

RUNNING HANDLER [os : Wait for reconnect] ************************************************************************
```

Where is the correct placement for `meta: clear_host_errors` in this case?

**Some additional info**

- restart of `network.service` takes about ~40 seconds. (Tried `async: 120` and `poll: 30`)
- established, non-ansible SSH connections recover with enough timeout
- re-run of *ansible* directly after the first exit work fine
- Interestingly enough, the skipping works fine with `ignore_errors: true` when using [Mitogen](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/):

```
TASK [os : Restart network service] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host-redacted]
skipping: [host-redacted]
fatal: [host-redacted]: FAILED! => {"msg": "EOF on stream; last 300 bytes received: 'ssh: connect to host aa.bb.cc.dd port 22: Connection refused\\r\\n'"}
...ignoring
```

This starts to look like a bug to me.

Comment: Wild guess: Disable "pipelining = true" ?

Comment: Added to "things-I-tried" list.